# Psychopy: How do I get the participant to respond using a specific key on the keyboard. Blue=f?

Tags: python, psychopy

Currently I have the code:

```py
import random
from psychopy import visual, event
win = visual.Window()

# A TextStim and five of each word-color pairs
stim = visual.TextStim(win)
pairs = 5 * [('blue', 'blue'), ('yellow', 'blue'), ('green', 'yellow'), ('red','red')]
random.shuffle(pairs)

# Loop through these pairs
for pair in pairs:
    # Set text and color
    stim.text = pair[0]
    stim.color = pair[1]

    # Show it and wait for answer
    stim.draw()
    win.flip()
    event.waitKeys()
```

I am trying to assign the key 'f' on the keyboard to the colour red, 'g' to blue, 'h' to yellow and 'j' to green, so when the participant presses 'f' when they see the colour red, I want to record the reaction time and I want it to say 'correct' or 'incorrect'? I have tried so many codes but I think I am putting them in the wrong order or I am going somewhere wrong!

Comment: I have used: event.waitKeys(keyList=['f', 'g', 'h', 'j']) so when the stimulus appears the participant can press either f g h j ... but I do not know how to specifically get f to equal red as a correct response, blue to equal g as a correct response etc.

Answer (score 1):

A neat way to do this is to use python dictionaries as key-meaning mapping. So in the beginning, define

```py
answer_keys = {'f': 'red', 'g': 'blue', 'h': 'yellow', 'j': 'green'}
```

As a simple demo, then

```py
answer_keys['f'] == 'blue'  # False
answer_keys['g'] == 'blue'  # True
```

To use this in your experiment, do:

```py
# Get answer and score it, and get RT
key, rt = event.waitKeys(keyList=answer_keys.keys(), timeStamped=True)[0]  # Only listen for allowed keys. [0] to get just first and only response
score = answer_keys[key] == pair[1]  # Whether the "meaining" of the key is identical to the ink color of the word.

# Show feedback
stim.text = 'correct' if score else 'incorrect'  # show text depending on score
stim.text += '\nRT=%i ms' %(rt*1000)  # Add RT to text, just for demo
stim.draw()
win.flip()
event.waitKeys()  # Wait, just to leave it on the screen for a while.
```

Comment: Thank you! That's a big help!! :D I am trying to record whether the answer is 'correct' or 'incorrect' not on the experiment screen but in the output if that makes sense? So at the moment I get this: [('f', 16.745426331006456)]
[('h', 17.391023434436647)]
[('j', 17.959463065635646)]
[('h', 18.541256578668253)]
[('g', 18.808297502459027)] ... Ideally I would like it to say 'true' if the answer was correct or 'false' if the answer was incorrect? Thanks again!

Comment: I believed I answered the question you actually asked. If you want to ask about analyzing saved data, ask a new question about that, detailing the structure of your data file.